# Why do these two queries (which I think are equivalent) rely on different keys?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, query-performance

We have a query that we don't like, since it ends up doing a full table scan.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    count(*) AS c, location.name
FROM
    study
LEFT JOIN
    location ON study.location_id = location.id
WHERE
    study.status = 'unread' AND
    study.deleted = '' AND
    study.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            study_id
        FROM
            studyassign
        WHERE (
            object_type = 'Group' AND
            object_id IN (
                SELECT
                    grp_id
                FROM
                    grpuser
                WHERE
                    user_id = '12')
            ) OR ( 
            object_type = 'User' AND
            object_id = '12')
        )
GROUP BY
    location.id;
```

This gives

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: study
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2015879
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: location
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: echo.study.location_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: studyassign
         type: index_subquery
possible_keys: studyassign_study_id_object_type_object_id_idx
          key: studyassign_study_id_object_type_object_id_idx
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: grpuser
         type: unique_subquery
possible_keys: grpuser_grp_id_user_id_idx,user_id
          key: grpuser_grp_id_user_id_idx
      key_len: 8
          ref: func,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using where
4 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

I went about making changes methodically, starting with the innermost sub queries. I was making progress.

But then I wanted to see what would happen if simply changed how the join was made.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    count(*) AS c, location.name
FROM
    study, location
WHERE
    study.location_id = location.id AND
    study.status = 'unread' AND
    study.deleted = '' AND
    study.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            study_id
        FROM
            studyassign
        WHERE (
            object_type = 'Group' AND
            object_id IN (
                SELECT
                    grp_id
                FROM
                    grpuser
                WHERE
                    user_id = '12')
            ) OR ( 
            object_type = 'User' AND
            object_id = '12')
        )
GROUP BY
    location.id;
```

The results from EXPLAIN are very different ...

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: location
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3667
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: study
         type: ref
possible_keys: location_id
          key: location_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: echo.location.id
         rows: 233
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: studyassign
         type: index_subquery
possible_keys: studyassign_study_id_object_type_object_id_idx
          key: studyassign_study_id_object_type_object_id_idx
      key_len: 4
          ref: func
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: grpuser
         type: unique_subquery
possible_keys: grpuser_grp_id_user_id_idx,user_id
          key: grpuser_grp_id_user_id_idx
      key_len: 8
          ref: func,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index; Using where
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First query has `LEFT JOIN`, the second one - `INNER JOIN`. They are not the same...

Comment: To enhance what @a1ex07 said. The two joins are equivalent only if there is a foreign key constarint between the 2 tables (`study` -> `location`). But even in that case, the optimizer is probably not that smart to know they are equivalent.

Comment: @ypercube ... can you help me understand how that foreign key constraint (there is one) makes the queries identical?